# Espaço gasto por variáveis

Tags: c

**Olá gostaria de saber como eu faço pra calcular  o espaço gasto por cada variáveis do código, funções.**

Exemplo tenho um código pra ordenar uma lista duplamente encadeada pelo SelectSort, porém  quero calcular o espaço gasto e não tenho ideia pensei em usar sizeof(int), em cada função pra somar o tamanho mas não deu certo? 
Alguém teria um link ou algo que ajude.

Exemplo : Tenho que calcular o espaço gasto pelas variáveis e função deste algorítimo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct cel{
    int conteudo;
    struct cel *seg;
    struct cel *ant;
}celula;


celula *inserirLista(celula *p, int x);
void insertionSort(celula *lst);
void Imprime(celula *lst);

int main(){
    /* inicio variaveis*/
    int i, n;
    celula c;
    celula *lst;
    celula *p;

    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    /* fim  variaveis*/


    lst = &c;
    lst->seg = NULL;
    lst->ant = NULL;
    p=lst;
    srand(time(NULL));
    n = 100000;

    for(i = 1; i <=n; i++)
        p = inserirLista(lst, rand()%1000);

    Imprime(lst);
    printf("\n\n");
    start = clock();
    insertionSort(lst);
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("\n\n Tempo: %.7f ", cpu_time_used);


    printf("\n\n");

    Imprime(lst);


}



void insertionSort(celula *lst){

    celula *p = lst;
    celula * q;

    lst = lst->seg->seg;

    while(lst != NULL){

        q = p;

        while(q->seg != lst){

            if (q->conteudo > lst->conteudo){

                int temp = lst->conteudo;
                lst->conteudo = q->conteudo;
                q->conteudo = temp;

            }else{

                q = q->seg;

            }

        }

        lst = lst->seg;

    }

}
celula *inserirLista(celula *p, int x){
    celula *nova;
    nova=(celula*)malloc(sizeof(celula));
    nova->conteudo = x;
    nova->seg=p->seg;
    nova->ant=p;

    p->seg =nova;
    return p;
}
void Imprime(celula *lst){
    celula * p = lst->seg;
    while (p->seg != NULL){
        printf("%d ", p->conteudo);
        p=p->seg;
    }
}
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Aqui damos respostas e não *links* para outros lugares, mas para respondermos precisamos de mais detalhes do que está fazendo, qual o problema que teve fazendo o que citou, qual o objetivo de obter esta informação, etc..

Comment: tente usar um depurador, talvez resolva o seu problema, tente usar o *GDB*

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que vc quer, o `sizeof()` retorna a quantidade em bytes que ocupa a sua variável, como vc quer fazer este calculo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem, se é uma lista duplamente encadeada, então você deve ter algo assim:

```
typedef struct NO {
    struct NO *prox;
    struct NO *anterior;
    int dados;
} NO;
```

E vamos supor que você tenha isso também:

```
 int numero_elementos_lista(NO *primeiro) {
     int x = 0;
     NO *no;
     for (no = primeiro; no != NULL; no = no->prox) {
         x++;
     }
     return x;
 }
```

Assim sendo, a memória utilizada será:

```
 int tamanho_em_bytes_da_lista(NO *primeiro) {
     return sizeof(NO) * numero_elementos_lista(primeiro);
 }
```

Comment: obrigado entendi acho que é assim mesmo!